# String Include some other strings

Tags: postgresql

How do I check in postgres that a varchar contains 'aaa' or 'bbb'?

I tried `myVarchar IN ('aaa', 'bbb')` but, obviously, it's true when myvarchar is exactly equal to 'aaa' or 'bbb'.

Comment: Use `LIKE` or `REGEXP`

Comment: Read the documentation: [9.7. Pattern Matching](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use ANY & LIKE operators together.

```
SELECT * FROM "myTable" WHERE "myColumn" LIKE ANY( ARRAY[ '%aaa%', '%bbb%' ] );
```

Comment: costs are very similar. tested on a table which has 200K records.

Comment: cool. thanks. I checked like `any( array on pg_class` - was slower then ORs

Comment: i checked your solution too. costs are same but run time is 2x slower in my setup, i think regex (similar operator) introduces extra overhead

Comment: regular expressions definitely introduce overhead

Answer (score 1):

for multiple similarity check the best fit in terms of speed and laconic syntax would be

```
SIMILAR TO '%(aaa|bbb|ccc)%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is your table:

```
 CREATE TABLE t
 (
     myVarchar varchar
 ) ;

 INSERT INTO t (myVarchar)
 VALUES
    ('something aaa else'),
    ('also some bbb'),
    ('maybe ccc') ;

-- (some random data, this query is PostgreSQL specific)
INSERT INTO t (myVarchar)
SELECT
    random()::varchar
FROM
    generate_series(1, 10000) ;
```

### SQL Standard approach:

You can do (in all SQL standard databases):

```
 SELECT
     *
 FROM
     t
 WHERE
     myVarchar LIKE '%aaa%' or myVarchar LIKE '%bbb%' ;
```

and you'll get:

```
 | myvarchar          |
 | :----------------- |
 | something aaa else |
 | also some bbb      |
```

### PostgreSQL specific approaches

Specifically for PostgreSQL, you can use a (single) regex with multiple values to look for:

```
 SELECT 
     *
 FROM
     t
 WHERE
     myVarchar ~ 'aaa|bbb' ;
```

```
 | myvarchar          |
 | :----------------- |
 | something aaa else |
 | also some bbb      |
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=dc5e29d1fba3a19abb23d6de11b3d730)*

If you need quick finds, you can use [trigram indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/pgtrgm.html), like this:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;  -- Only needed if extension not already installed
CREATE INDEX myVarchar_like_idx 
   ON t 
   USING GIST (myVarchar gist_trgm_ops);
```

... the query using `LIKE` will be much faster.